# Аngular JS  не асинхронный запрос

Tags: javascript

Всем доброго дня, подскажите каким образом можно написать directive, что бы он сначала выполнял $http.$post запрос, а потом уже из полученных данных переходил к постройке шаблона ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Похоже вы ещё не поняли как именно нужно работать с AngularJS, а именно как устроен data-binding. Посмотрите [пример](http://jsfiddle.net/J8F4k/),  в нем данные приходят с задержкой 1сек.

Comment: Так оно и есть, ) Пример понятен, спасибо, тогда другой вопрос а если мне нужно исходя из полученных данных менять структуру template:
Например приходит от $http.$post = 1  
template: '<div> 66666 </div>' 
а если приходит null то 
template: '<p> 9999 </p>'

Comment: Или так же запросом передавать шаблон? в template:

Comment: Так нельзя делать, структура должна быть конечна и меняться в зависимости от значений переменных. Вот [пример с $http][1].

http://jsfiddle.net/J8F4k/2/

Comment: Вот облом, Спасибо теперь все понятно.

Comment: ну почему же нельзя? Структуру можно менять при помощи ng-if, ng-switch и т.п. Что может помешать-то?

Comment: Если быть точным ng-if, ng-switch и другие. не меняют структуру шаблона, они являются частью шаблона.

Comment: ведь так работают все шаблоны, не только ангуляровские, и тут нет абсолютно ничего особенного. А задачу выполняет:

    <div ng-if="$http.$post == 1"> {{$http.$post}} </div>
    <p ng-if="$http.$post != 1"> {{$http.$post}} </p>